# AnjularJS ng-repeat get item from different scope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two different scope objects. First one is 'Details' object, the second one is 'Country' object. I want to fetch data from my 'Country' object using 'CountryId' which is in the 'Details' object.

I have created a function in my scope and I can fetch my Country data (please see the below code. it is working properly) but I'm sure that it should be a better way in AngularJS. 
Is there?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.FindSpecificItem = function(obj, field, value, returnField) {
            return jQuery.grep(obj, function(item) {
                return (item[field] == value);
            })[0][returnField];
        };
        $scope.details = [{
            "Name": "John",
            "CountryId": "1"
        }, {
            "Name": "Dave",
            "CountryId": "2"
        }]
        $scope.Countries = [{
            "Id": "1",
            "Country": "USA"
        }, {
            "Id": "2",
            "Country": "England"
        }]
    });
</script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="d in details">
                <td>{{d.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{FindSpecificItem(Countries,"Id",d.CountryId,"Country")}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could simply go for Countries[d.CountryId -1].Country if they are sorted from id 1-x and there are no gaps. If not its still a got idea to make an indexed array with the id value as key and then containing your country objects.

Comment: as far as I can tell there is only one scope in your controller...

Comment: @Doomenik thanks for your suggestion but actually this is a demo code. In my real arrays have lots of records and there is no simple correlation between them

Comment: @Grcn thats why you cold go for an indexed array, just write the object into an indexed array. This way the Countries[d.CountryId -1].Country works every time. The only downside would be if you have multiple countries with the same id. Than you would need another loop, which should be also no problem.

Comment: dont use angular forEach as it always completes its iterations and does not support break. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to pull out the use of JQuery, you could use `ECMAScript 6`, `array.Find` as :

One line of code:

```
$scope.FindSpecificItem = function(Id) {
   return $scope.Countries.find(x => x.Id === Id).Country;
}
```

Please see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for its limited support across browsers.

DEMO:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.FindSpecificItem = function(Id) {
    return $scope.Countries.find(x => x.Id === Id).Country;
  }

  $scope.details = [{
      "Name": "John",
      "CountryId": "1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Dave",
      "CountryId": "2"
    }
  ]

  $scope.Countries = [{
      "Id": "1",
      "Country": "USA"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "Country": "England"
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="d in details">
        <td>{{d.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{FindSpecificItem(d.CountryId)}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use angular `forEach` loop. like this:

```js
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

        $scope.FindSpecificItem  = function(id) {
        var country1 = "";
          angular.forEach($scope.Countries,function(country){
              if(country.Id == id)
                country1 = country.Country;
          })
          
          return country1;
        };

        $scope.details = [
            {
                "Name": "John",
                "CountryId": "1"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Dave",
                "CountryId": "2"
            }]

        $scope.Countries = [
            {
                "Id": "1",
                "Country": "USA"
            },
            {
                "Id": "2",
                "Country": "England"
            }]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="d in details">
                <td>{{d.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{FindSpecificItem(d.CountryId)}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter Countries using `filter` function

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.getCountry=function(id){
    console.log("Calling "+id);
    var countries=$scope.Countries.filter(function(item){
     console.log(item.Id===id)
        return item.Id===id;
     
     })
    return countries[0].Country;
    }


    $scope.details = [{
        "Name": "John",
        "CountryId": "1"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Dave",
        "CountryId": "2"
      }
    ]

    $scope.Countries = [{
        "Id": "1",
        "Country": "USA"
      },
      {
        "Id": "2",
        "Country": "England"
      }
    ]
  });
</script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="d in details">
        <td>{{d.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{getCountry(d.CountryId)}}

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use jquery here. Just return it using simple for loop, don't use [**angular.forEach()**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach), as it does not support `break`.

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
 app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

  $scope.FindSpecificItem  = function(value) {
   for (var i = 0; i<$scope.Countries.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.Countries[i].Id == value.CountryId) {
     return $scope.Countries[i].Country;
    }
   }
  };

  $scope.details = [
  {
   "Name": "John",
   "CountryId": "1"
  },
  {
   "Name": "Dave",
   "CountryId": "2"
  }]

  $scope.Countries = [
  {
   "Id": "1",
   "Country": "USA"
  },
  {
   "Id": "2",
   "Country": "England"
  }]
 });
</script>

<body>

 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="d in details">
    <td>{{d.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{FindSpecificItem(d)}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it simply using **filter** of angularJS.

filter can be used in JS as well as in HTML. Here I am mentioning filter in HTML because filter in JS is already mentioned above.

Try this in HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="d in details">
      <td>{{d.Name}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="country in Countries| 
        filter :{Id:d.CountryId }">{{country.Country}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is the controller with no extra JS method

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.details = [
    {
      "Name": "John",
      "CountryId": "1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Dave",
      "CountryId": "2"
    }];

  $scope.Countries = [
    {
      "Id": "1",
      "Country": "USA"
    },
    {
      "Id": "2",
      "Country": "England"
    }];
}]);
```

Here is the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/hjemVfAnrTJixpVF2NMN?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.FindSpecificItem  = function(countryId) {
    var result = "";
      angular.forEach($scope.Countries,function(country){
          if(country.Id == countryId)
            result = country.Country;
      })

      return result;
    };
    $scope.details = [{
        "Name": "John",
        "CountryId": "1"
    }, {
        "Name": "Dave",
        "CountryId": "2"
    }]
    $scope.Countries = [{
        "Id": "1",
        "Country": "USA"
    }, {
        "Id": "2",
        "Country": "England"
    }]
  });
</script>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="d in details">
            <td>{{d.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{FindSpecificItem(d.CountryId)}}
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```